# antlr3 - ignore a token / parse it only once

Tags: java, antlr3

At the moment I try to parse a text like

"**play** by the way **by** band by"

to parse a command for a mediaplayer.
I got problems if the **play** and **by** token is in the name of a song or an artist. 
How can I ignore the multiple token in the songname and artist or parse the token only once in the directions I want?

That is my .g file:

```
text returns [String value]
 : speech=wordExp (space s1=name)? (byartist space a1=name)? {
        command = $speech.text;
        match = $s1.text;
        artist = $a1.text;
   }
 ;

name 
 : s1 = (WORD (space  s2 = WORD)*) 
 ;

byartist 
 : space BY 
 ;

wordExp 
 : PLAY | STOP
 ;

//Lexer
PLAY   : 'play';
STOP : 'stop';
BY : 'by';
space : ' ';
WORD : ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' )*; // digits in here?
WS : ('\t' | '\r'| '\n') {
        $channel=HIDDEN;
    }
 ;
```

Comment: The problem is, it's a bit ambigous, e.g. which is correct: "ABC **by** by ba" or "ABC by **by** ba". Are you assuming that the song name contains by only once?

Comment: no I do not assume that it comes up only once. Thee is a database behind it and I guess I have to walk though it if I have something like "play ABC **by by by** artist **by**". for example "select ABC by from ..." and select ABC by by from ..." and so on. But I want to avoid that.

Comment: So how do you tell which is correct in my example?

Comment: Just thought about it... I guess there is no way to parse it without touching the database... except I get a brilliant idea

Comment: Is there a way to walk though the by's to try every option? If not it seems like antlr wouldnt be not the right technology for my project...

Comment: `(space s1=name)? (byartist space a1=name)?` is also ambiguous, "by ABC" could mean by artist ABC, or a song called "by ABC". There are many ways of solving the first problem in the grammar, e.g. have names in quotes `play "by the way" by "rhcp"`, or use a more exotic separation token, e.g. `play by the way # rhcp` or have the `by` token capitalized `play by the way BY rhcp`

Comment: That is a smart solution! Sorry I fogot the mention it is a voicecommand that should be parsed, so I can not include hashtags instead of "by". I guess I need something like "**play** by the way **by artist** red hot chili peppers".

Comment: But another problem ocoured: is I say "**play** play with me" it throws an error because the parser dont like the multiple use of **play**. the word **play** is in use only in the beginning. how can I catch this?

Comment: Have name match `WORD | PLAY | STOP` etc.

Comment: What do you mean? where should I put it in?